# Ideal prime to $f$ iff the norm of the ideal is relatively prime to $f$

Tags: ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ideals, finite-fields, proof-explanation

I have been beating my head at it for the last two days but I don't understand the proof provided in the picture for the part (i) of the lemma. This David Cox book, *Primes of the form* $x^2+ny^2$, is giving me nightmares and I would be really grateful if somebody can explain the proof to me in detail unlike the heavily consolidated one in the book.

All I want is somebody please explain me his proof in greater detail so that I understand it completely. Also can someone please suggest a good book with clear proofs for algebraic number theory? I do follow Alaca and Williams but the book is missing the good content like the Part 7 of **Cox's 'Primes of the form $x^2+ny^2$'**. The stuff I see in this book, I haven't seen them anywhere.

Thank you so much for your help. [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For **(i)** The first equivalence is the definition of being surjective and the second holds because $\mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{a} $ is finite. Now the structure theorem for finite abelian groups tell us that

$\mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{a} \simeq \mathbb{Z}/d_1 \mathbb{Z} \times \ldots \times\mathbb{Z}/d_n \mathbb{Z} $

where $d_i \mid d_j$ for $1\leq i<j \leq n$, thus $m_f$ will be an isomorphism iff the corresponding multiplication by $f$ from  $\mathbb{Z}/d_1 \mathbb{Z} \times \ldots \times\mathbb{Z}/d_n \mathbb{Z} $ to itself is an isomorphism.

This happens iff $1\in \mathbb{Z}/d_1 \mathbb{Z} \times \ldots \times\mathbb{Z}/d_n \mathbb{Z} $ is in its image,i.e., if and only if for each $1\leq i\leq n$ there exist $n_i$ such that $f\cdot n_i \equiv 1 \;(\bmod\; d_i)$ which is the same as saying that $f$ is relatively prime to each $d_i$ or that is relatively prime to $N(\mathfrak{a})=d_1 \cdots d_n$.

For **(ii)** $\beta \mathfrak{a} \subset \mathfrak{a}$ implies $\beta \in \mathcal{O}_K$ because $\mathfrak{a}$ is a finitely generated  abelian group, the rest of the proof I think is clear enough (remember $f=[\mathcal{O}_K : \mathcal{O}]$  so $f \cdot\mathcal{O}_K \subset \mathcal{O}$ )

Comment: Hi, I am quite new to this and I don't understand what you mean by 'The first equivalence is the definition of being surjective'. Also how the second holds because O/a is finite.

Comment: You're right I should explain bettter: $m_f$ is surjective iff  its image $f\mathcal{O}/ \mathfrak{a}$ is the entire $\mathcal{O}/ \mathfrak{a}$ or $f\mathcal{O}/ \mathfrak{a}=(f\mathcal{O}+\mathfrak{a})/\mathfrak{a}=\mathcal{O}/ \mathfrak{a}$ that is $f\mathcal{O}+\mathfrak{a}=\mathcal{O}$.

Comment: Also, a map from a finite set to any set of the same cardinality is surjective iff is inyective by the pigeonhole principle.

Comment: Thank you so much. That makes sense to me. You explained it nicely, sir!

Comment: CRKarl Hi! Now when I was doing this by myself I don't understand one thing in your comment above - Why did you decide to add an $\mathfrak{a}$ to the equation and then go on and show that the image is indeed $\mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{a}$? How did you come up with the first equality in your comment above? Thanks.

Comment: What I meant was: $m_f$ is surjective $\iff$ $\mathcal{O}/ \mathfrak{a}=f\mathcal{O}/ \mathfrak{a} \iff \mathcal{O}/ \mathfrak{a}=(f\mathcal{O}+\mathfrak{a}) / \mathfrak{a}\iff \mathcal{O}=f\mathcal{O}+\mathfrak{a} $. I just added $\mathfrak{a}$ to make $\mathfrak{a} \subset f\mathcal{O}+\mathfrak{a}$ and use of the correspondence between subgroups of $\mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{a}$ and subgroups of $\mathcal{O}$ containing  $\mathfrak{a}$.